# Do I need html5shiv if using webshim project?

Tags: webshim

I am using form polyfill from [aFarkas/webshim](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim) in a project. The same project uses [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) to support `<nav>` and `<section>`.

README file of webshim project lists "HTML5 shiv" as one of its features. Does this mean I do not need to separately include html5shiv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you found an error. This was part of webshim, but isn't anymore. I will remove this part from the readme. Thanks.

You need to include the html5shiv.